# Permission denied when pulling Docker image from Google Cloud Container Registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am getting a permission denied error message when pulling a docker image from the Google Cloud Container Registry, in a Compute Engine VM:

```
gcloud docker pull -- gcr.io/your-project-id/example-image
```

Results in:

> FATA[0000] Post
>   http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/images/create?fromImage=gcr.io%2Fyour-project-id%2Fexample-image%3Alatest:
>   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to
>   connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

I got the "gcloud docker pull" command from a sample and the docs: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pulling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running as super user did the trick:

```
sudo gcloud docker pull -- gcr.io/your-project-id/example-image
```

Comment: Above command is not supported for Docker client versions above 18.03.

Moving forward need to use gcloud as credentials helper.
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/deprecation-notices#gcloud-docker

Answer (score 5):

Adding user to docker group worked for me. Added benefit is that, after adding the user to docker group, you will not have to use sudo along with docker commands.

*sudo usermod -a -G docker ${USER}*

Note: **It requires a machine restart**

Now you can use docker pull 
*gcloud docker pull -- gcr.io/your-project-id/example-image*

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/troubleshooting